# How do I trace string from right-side in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four|five';
```

This regex `/^(\w+)\|/` matches first word *(from left side)*. In other word, `$1` returns `one`. Now I need to get second word from the right side (`four`).

EX1:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three';
```

I want `two`.

EX2:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four';
```

I want `three`.

EX3:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four|five|six|seven';
```

I want `six`.

Always I want second word from the right side. How can I do that?

Comment: Let's see your Javascript code as well.

Comment: [`str.match(/\|(\w+)\|\w+$/)[1]`](https://regex101.com/r/vZ5yR2/1). In JS, there is no other way.

Comment: @Snorlax What? Actually I need to check `if(variable.test(/second-word-form-right/) == 'four') { return true; }`

Comment: What about `one|two`?  Would you want `one`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep .....

Comment: @BrendanAbel Nope ....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why did you say *In JS* ? Is there any other solution in other languages *(like PHP)* ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that doesn't work if there are only two words

Comment: Great point ^ ... this works `\|?(\w+)\|\w+$`

Comment: In .NET,  or PyPi Python, or Boost, I could use capture collection as well. Anyway, what I suggest is the quickest. Patrick's solution is using a lookahead - it is not that quick.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my answer. FYI the leading `\|` is completely unecessary. `\w+` is greedy so that won't ever be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you want to do this with pure regular expressions, you can actually do this:

`(?:(.*)\|){2}`

Check out the matched group on this: http://regexr.com/3crfr

Then for Javascript (or any other language), simply extract the group. You could do that like this:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four';
console.log(/(?:(.*)\|){2}/g.exec(variable)[1]);
```

Works fine, yeah?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/\w+(?=\|\w+$)/
```

```js
var regexp = /\w+(?=\|\w+$)/;

document.write(`<pre>
${[
  'one|two|three',
  'one|two|three|four',
  'one|two|three|four|five',
  'one|two|three|four|five|six'
].map(input=>`${input}=>${regexp.exec(input)[0]}`).join('\n')}
</pre>`)
```

If that doesn't convince you, here's a [link to regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/jD7qC0/1) demonstrating it as well.

If a lookahead is too slow for you, you can also try:

```
/(\w+)\|\w+$/
```

which still does the same thing, except now the result is stored in a group instead of returned directly, so change `regexp.exec(input)[0]` to `regexp.exec(input)[1]`:

```js
var regexp = /(\w+)\|\w+$/;

document.write(`<pre>
${[
  'one|two|three',
  'one|two|three|four',
  'one|two|three|four|five',
  'one|two|three|four|five|six'
].map(input=>`${input}=>${regexp.exec(input)[1]}`).join('\n')}
</pre>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the regular expression, you can do this:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four';
var result = variable.split("|");
console.log(result[result.length - 2]);
```

If you want to do it with a regular expression, you can do this:

```
var variable = 'one|two|three|four';
console.log(variable.match(/\|(\w+)\|\w+$/)[1]);
```

Either way works fine.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative approach , beginning at the end of input string. At first `|` character begin inner loop, at second `|` character break outer loop

```js
var variable = "one|two|three|four|five"
, i = variable.length
, match = [];
while (true) {
  if (variable[i] === "|") {
    while (variable[--i] !== "|") {
      match.push(variable[i]);
    }
    match = match.reverse().join("");
    break;
  }
  --i
};

console.log(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use the EOL anchor like this `[^|]+(?=\|[^|]+$)`